# Find Where the Function $3x^4-4x^3-12x^2+5$ is Increasing and Decreasing

Tags: calculus

Can someone tell me how the chart and the graph shown in figure 2 are analogous? For example, where is $f(0)= 5$? The book states that $f(0)= 5$ is the local maximum value; however, I can not determine that by looking at the graph.

Is this a special graph or is there a special way of reading it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0)=5$ is where the blue curve crosses the vertical axis. If $x=0$ then the value of the function is $3 \times 0-4\times 0-12\times 0+5=5$. It is a local maximum because the graph reaches a peak at that point. If the graph were a hillside and you put a marble on it at that point, the marble would roll down on one side or the other.

Comment: This was a real silly question I guess. Thank you.